# How to format output types with react-hook-form?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm using react-hook-form with typescript to send the input data to the server and create tasks. I am setting the form defaultValues as strings:

```
defaultValues: {
      taskType: "",
      title: "",
      start: "",
      notes: "",
      tags: "",
}
```

But before sending this values to the API I need to map the types so they can fit the expected ones. I am doing that with a map function. This is an example of my map function:

```
function formatAnyTask(formData: TaskFormInputs, taskType: TaskTypes): AnyTask {
  const { title, careRecipient } = formData;
  const start = formatDate(formData.start);
  const durationSeconds = convertMinutesToSeconds(formData.durationSeconds);
  const notes = formData.notes === "" ? null : [formData.notes];
  const tags = formData.tags === "" ? null : [formData.tags];

  return {
    taskType,
    title,
    start,
    notes,
    tags,
    durationSeconds,
    careRecipient,
  };
}
```

My question is: Is there a better, a recommended or a best practice way to do this rather than creating mapping functions to match the output types?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a form validation method such as Zod? I have used it and it works well even with headless UI components like antd and shadcn

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries to validate the form data with the react hook forms?

Check [this link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/react-form-validation-zod-react-hook-form/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).